# Ejecutar archivo .sql desde NodeJs - Sql Server

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, nodejs

Archivo .sql

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SP_NotasEstudiantesMateria_G]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_NotasEstudiantesMateria_G] AS' 
END
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Arlington
-- Create date: 04-11-2018
-- Description: Trae las notas de los estudiantes de determinado curso en determinado año y de determinada materia
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Arlington
-- Create date: 16-06-2019
-- Description: Se agrega logica para manejar las ausencias
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Arlington
-- Create date: 19-06-2019
-- Description: Se quita join con la tabla adinasistencias
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Arlington
-- Create date: 19-06-2019
-- Description: test sdf kjsdfk ndskgn fskdnkn
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_NotasEstudiantesMateria_G]

    @pIdAñoLectivo INT,
    @pIdCurso INT,
    @pIdMateria INT,
    @pIdMaestro BIGINT      

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE 
    @IdAñoLectivo INT = @pIdAñoLectivo, 
    @IdCurso INT = @pIdCurso,
    @IdMaestro INT = @pIdMaestro,
    @IdMateria BIGINT = @pIdMateria

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT MC.Sec AS SecMatCurso, ET.IdTercero, CONCAT(ET.Papellido,' ',ET.Sapellido,' ',ET.Pnombre,' ',ET.Snombre) AS NombreComp 
        , MR.Sec AS IdMateria, MR.NomMateria, MT.Sec AS IdMatricula, P1, 
        (SELECT CantInasistencias 
        FROM ADInasistencia 
        WHERE IdEstudiante = ET.IdTercero 
        AND IdCurso = @IdCurso
        AND IdMateria = @IdMateria
        AND IdPeriodo = 1) AS IAP1, P2, (SELECT CantInasistencias 
        FROM ADInasistencia 
        WHERE IdEstudiante = ET.IdTercero 
        AND IdCurso = @IdCurso
        AND IdMateria = @IdMateria
        AND IdPeriodo = 2) IAP2, P3, (SELECT CantInasistencias 
        FROM ADInasistencia 
        WHERE IdEstudiante = ET.IdTercero
        AND IdCurso = @IdCurso
        AND IdMateria = @IdMateria
        AND IdPeriodo = 3)IAP3, P4, (SELECT CantInasistencias 
        FROM ADInasistencia 
        WHERE IdEstudiante = ET.IdTercero 
        AND IdCurso = @IdCurso
        AND IdMateria = @IdMateria
        AND IdPeriodo = 4)IAP4,  ((P1 + P2 + P3 + P4) / 4) AS Prom   
        FROM ADTerceros ET 
        INNER JOIN ADMatriculas MT ON ET.IdTercero = MT.IdEstudiante AND MT.IdAñoLectivo = @IdAñoLectivo
        INNER JOIN ADCursos CS ON MT.IdCurso = CS.Sec
        INNER JOIN ADMateriasCursos MC ON CS.Sec = MC.IdCurso
        INNER JOIN ADMaterias MR ON MC.IdMateria = MR.Sec
        LEFT JOIN ADNotas NT ON MC.Sec = NT.SecMatCurso AND NT.IdEstudiante = ET.IdTercero AND NT.IdMatricula = MT.Sec
        WHERE CS.Sec = @IdCurso AND MR.Sec = @IdMateria AND MC.IdMaestro = @IdMaestro AND MT.Cancelada = 0 ORDER BY NombreComp
END
```

Error en response:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Code Js:

```
const sql = require('mssql')    
var text = fs.readFileSync("./testsql.sql", "utf-8");

sql.connect(config, function (err) {

    if (err) console.log(err);
    const request = new sql.Request()
    request.batch(text, (err, result) => {
        return res.status(200).json({
            result: (err)? err: result
        });
    })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Al procedimiento almacenado no le están llegando los parámetros, de ahí que te reporta error en la asignación de @idCurso. Aún así, es un poco extraño que te reporte @idCurso y no @pIdCurso.

Como primera prueba, puedes cambiar la definición del procedure, estableciendo un valor por defecto. No para que funcione ni mucho menos, sino para ver el cambio en el error.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_NotasEstudiantesMateria_G]

    @pIdAñoLectivo INT = 0,
    @pIdCurso INT = 0,
    @pIdMateria INT = 0,
    @pIdMaestro BIGINT = 0      

AS
```

Si esto te resuelve correcto, u otro tipo de error, creo que deberías de mirar como le envías los parámetros.

Te puede servir de ayuda este enlace donde se envían parámetros a Sql Server
[Passing a node.js parameter in sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851653/how-to-pass-parameter-to-mssql-query-in-node-js)